# What Happened to Jonathan Crane after the events of Gotham Episode 15: "The Scarecrow"?

Tags: dc, gotham

After seeing various villains being shown in Gotham (Penguin, Victor Zsass, Mr. Freeze, etc.), I have noticed that nothing has been shown about the condition of Jonathan Crane after the events of "The Scarecrow", where a doctor watching over Jonathan has the following conversation with Detective James Gordon:

> **Gordon:** So, he's still in fear?
>
> **Doctor:** Well, not just fear, detective. Jonathan's brain activity shows he's in a state of intense terror.
>
> **Gordon:** How long until it goes away?
>
> **Doctor:** Well, that's the thing, detective; we can't be certain it ever will. *(Looks through the glass at Jonathan)* Imagine the thing you fear most in the world. Imagine that's all you see, every waking moment.

We are then shown a shot of an evil-looking scarecrow looming over Jonathan as he screams in terror, desperate to escape the terrifying figure. After that, the episode ends, and nothing more is said about Crane.

Does anyone know what happened afterwards, through interviews, or a Gotham-related source, etc.?

Comment: Why do you assume his condition is changed since then?

Comment: No news is no news; Generalissimo Francisco Franco is still dead.

Answer (score 4):

We got to know about Jonathan Crane's fate later on in season 4. In S04E01 aka "Pax Penguina", we see Jonathan Crane still in Arkham afraid of scarecrows; the local gang even used his fear of scarecrows to control him to do their bidding. In the end:

> The gang decides to attack the club's inauguration and have Jonathan make more toxin and then lock him in a closet with a scarecrow. He then begins to have a severe hallucination with the scarecrow, who seemingly comes to life.
>  
>  [...]
>  
>  Grady returns to Crane's house to get more toxin from Jonathan. However, he discovers Jonathan has adopted a new persona, naming himself **"The Scarecrow"** and sprays Grady with fear gas.
>  
>  [Wikipedia, Pax Penguina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_Penguina)

He did appear in [S04E02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fear_Reaper) too.